# prove that if $L(f,P)=U(f,P)$ then $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Suppose that $f$ is a bounded function on $[a,b]$ and there exists a partition $P $of $[a,b] $such that $L(f,P)=U(f,P)$. Prove that $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$

I know that $L(f,P)=U(f,P)$ meaning $f$ is Darboux integrable, I also know that I need to prove that $f'(x)=0$ to show that $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$. But I don't know how to link those two.

Comment: Please look at william Wade's introduction to anaysis book. It is explained there so good.

Comment: do you have any free version link of this book?

Comment: There may be exist on the website " libgen.info "

Comment: I'll check that out, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Suppose $f$ is a real-valued function defined on some closed interval $I = [\alpha, \beta]$, and $\inf\{f(x) : x \in I\} = \sup \{f(x) : x \in I\}$. What does this tell you about the set of values of $f$ on $I$?

Comment: oh, the least upper bound and the greatest lower bound are the same so the values of $f$ on $I$ are the same , thank you.